# Blue color lines on display

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I recently updated to Mavericks OS of my MacBook Pro 13" inch which was bought on October 2012. I am having blue colored lines and strange shapes all over the display. I dont know whether its hardware or software issue. The following images will reveal my issue.

[image: Login Screen]

Comment: Do you see these anomalies all the time or when using specific applications? Did this start after upgrading to OS X 10.9?

Comment: Do they appear if you ⇧-boot (Safe Mode)? Do they appear if you ⌘S-boot (Single User Mode)?

Comment: @GrahamMiln It comes and goes often. But when I am using Xcode(Its used to build iOS and Mac Apps), i'll get more and more lines all over display.

Comment: @grgarside i never tried those method.. Will try today and let u know.

Answer (score 1):

Could be graphics card issue, check my question [Macbook pro checkered display, safeboot works](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58896/macbook-pro-checkered-display-safeboot-works)

I ended up replacing the logic board.

P.S: Talk to customer relations instead of call center and ask for free service in case of hardware failure.